# Error with script export_gcal_to_gsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have searched for the answer to my error, but no luck. I found this Google App Script to be able to search within a date range on a private Google Calendar.
I tried changing the dates on the line of code that has the error.
It raises the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null. (line 39, file
>   "Code")Dismiss.

The line of code that raises the error is:

```
 var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("Feburary 5, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("March 2, 2018 23:59:59 CST"));


function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
    var mycal = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/compucom.com_3hd44kal0eabhffqoqgijs6it8%40group.calendar.google.com/private-dd5e021b521802f13b6d664dd3d275fa/basic.ics";
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("Feburary 5, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("March 2, 2018 23:59:59 CST"));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,14);
    range.setValues(header);
    for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    var row=i+2;
    var myformula_placeholder = '';
    var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
    var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,14);
    range.setValues(details);
    var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);
    cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
    cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

    }
    }
    function onOpen() {
      Browser.msgBox('App Instructions - Please Read This Message', '1) Click Tools then Script Editor\\n2) Read/update the code with your desired values.\\n3) Then when ready click Run export_gcal_to_gsheet from the script editor.', Browser.Buttons.OK);

    }
```

Comment: What about the other lines of code, specifically the ones that create `cal`? Those are pretty important too. What have you tried to do to fix this error, and what has your research into this error message taught you?

Comment: Sorry, I am brand new to Google App Script.

Comment: function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){

Comment: Edit your question to include the code - do not put code blocks into the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

You receive that error, `Cannot call method "getEvents" of null`, because the `cal` variable is null.

Per the documentation reference for Google Calendar's [`getCalendarById` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById(String)), `null` is returned if the calendar does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.

Either your calendar id is incorrect, or you do not have permission to access that calendar (i.e. it is neither shared with you or public). When that issue is resolved, your script will be able to check its events.

I would recommend amending that portion of the script to:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
if(!cal) {
    Browser.msgBox("Unable to access calendar with id=" + mycal);
    return;
}
var events = cal.getEvents(....
```

Which will avoid the null reference and alert you to an issue with the calendar privacy, or an issue with its id.

Comment: I have elevated rights to this private shared calendar. I also tried this ID, it does not work same error.Integrate calendar
Calendar ID
compucom.com_3hd44kal0eabhffqoqgijs6it8@group.calendar.google.com

Comment: I am now trying by Calendar Name instead of Calendar ID. But I get an error. ReferenceError: "cal" is not defined. (line 41, file "Code"). Which points to the line of code with the date range. This is what I am trying now.                                                                                                  // Gets the public calendar named "Calendar Name".
 var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Calendar Name');
 Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length);

Comment: @PatBruno of course you get that error - your new code sets the variable with the calendar as `calendars` and not `cal`. So you must update your variable names.

Comment: I have tried everything that i read about to get this to work. When I set it up to search by ID, it should return this....Calendar — the calendar with the given ID, or null if the calendar does not exist or the user cannot access it. I do have access to it. Could it be blocked by my company. I also tried this from my home network, same results. I get "cannot call method "Get Events" of null. Line 39

Answer (score 0):

The `getCalendarById` method requires a calendar id instead of a calendar address. Try replacing the address for `mycal` variable by the id. 
A calendar id for google calendar can be found in the "Integrate Calendar" option in "Settings for my calendar" dropdown. It should look like "blah@blah.xxx" or "blah@group.calendar.google.com"

Answer (score 0):

I tried just changing `mycal = calendar` email to `calendar id` and worked perfect